# Input format of date

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a datepicker in my view (xaml):

```
<DatePicker Name="birthday" SelectedDate="{Binding Birthday, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
```

Current input format has to be `dd.MM.yyy`, like 23.02.2015. I would like that the users just have to input a date in format `ddMMyy`, like 230215 and this is automatically "resolved" to 23.02.2015. How is that possible?

Comment: Interestingly this guy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074206/wpf-datepicker-text-not-updating-after-binding-source-update) is trying to do the same. Without any solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 string dt = "230215";
 string formatted = DateTime.ParseExact(dt,"ddMMyy").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Looks like this has to be done code-behind? I try to avoid this and stick to MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it on your properties setter?

```
private string _birthday;

public string Birthday
{
     get{ return _birthday; }
     set
     {
         _birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(value,"ddMMyy").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
     }
}
```

Comment: The property is a (nullable) `DateTime`, not a `string`. Can this be done like that anyhow?

Comment: @mosquito87 You could have the backing field be a `DateTime?`  Then have two properties that expose it.  One as a `string` like above and another as an actual `DateTime?`.  The `string` property would only be used to wire up to your UI.

Comment: How can I bind a `DatePicker` to a string?